# How to prevent fullcalendar to show the start-hour in the event headline?

Tags: fullcalendar

in the monthview fullcalendar has the nice feature to show the start time in the top line of non-allDay events. This might be useful if you don't want to provide further details in the event title.

I want to show several details in the month view, like start and end time (15.00 - 18-00), location, etc.

This leads to the fact that fullcalendar shows my events like this: "15 15.00 - 18.00".

Is there any way to prevent fullcalendar from showing the start time OR is there any way to get fullcalendar to show the full timespan (15.00 - 18.00)?

Thanks.
Alex

Answer (score 21):

Try this, it works for me:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     displayEventTime : false
});
```

That should prevent fullcalendar to show the start-hour in the event headline.

Answer (score 10):

This is what you are looking for...

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/

```
timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
```

I beleive if you want to remove it all you would have to do is include an empty string aka...

```
timeFormat: ''(, or no , depending on if there is another object following)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

I set the timeFormat, but I overlooked the brackets. With timeFormat: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}' I get exactly what I want.

This piece of software is really great.

Comment: I agree, very helpful api. Don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: i'm using version 2.3.1 and finding that the above solution does not work, but providing a single whitespace does: `' '`.

Answer (score 4):

As @Isaak Kleinman said in a comment, this is the correct syntax:

```
timeFormat: ' ',       //with the space
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I got the solution though

Add this to your code:

```
displayEventEnd: true,
timeFormat: 'h:mma',
```